# Does Python's logging.config.dictConfig() apply the logger's configuration settings?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, logging

I've been trying to implement a basic logger that writes to a file in Python 3.5, loading the settings from a JSON config file.
I'll show my code first;

`log_config.json`

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": "false",
    "logging": {
        "formatters": {
            "basic": {
                "class": "logging.Formatter",
                "style": "%",
                "datefmt": "%I:%M:%S",
                "format": "[%(asctime)] %(levelname:<8s): (name:<4s): %(message)"
            }
        },

        "handlers": {
            "file": {
                "class": "logging.handlers.FileHandler",
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "formatter": "basic",
                "filename": "test.log",
                "mode": "a",
                "encoding": "utf-8"
            }
        },

        "loggers": { },

        "root": {
            "handlers": ["file"],
            "level": "DEBUG"
        }
    }
}
```

And `logger.py`

```
import json
import logging
import logging.config

logging.basicConfig()
with open("log_config.json", "r") as fd:
    logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(fd))

logger = logging.getLogger()  # Returns the "root" logger
print(logger.getEffectiveLevel())  # Check what level of messages will be shown

logger.debug("Test debug message")
logger.info("Test info message")
logger.warn("Test warning message")
logger.error("Test error message")
logger.critical("Test critical message")
```

When run with `python3 logger.py` produces the output (in the terminal);

```
30
WARNING:root:Test warning message
ERROR:root:Test error message
CRITICAL:root:Test critical message
```

First; Looking at  [Python's logging levels](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging-levels). 30 is the default logging level of 'WARNING'. This contradicts the setting for both of the `level` properties I set in the handler and the root logger. It seems the JSON is incorrect or I have missed a function call to apply it.

Second; [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805905/python-logging-dictconfig) makes me think that although I load the config with the call of `dictConfig()`, I still need to apply it to the logging with further calls in my `logger.py` file. It seems a bit redundant that you have the config and then have to verbosely apply each setting anyway.

Additionally; When I tried using the [Configuration file format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format) it worked as I thought it would. Namely; loading the file with one function call and being able to make logging calls straight away. This is confusing, because why would the older `fileConfig()` call used with this format offer a more streamlined functionality than `dictConfig()` with JSON or YAML?

Ultimately, I'm a bit confused and would like to figure this out. I appreciate your time and help.

EDIT: From Alex.P's comment, I added the following handler to `log_config.json` and changed the handler the root to it.

```
"console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "basic",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
```

Checking the output, it is the same as above.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I think you have only set up logging to a file, and not to a console, so maybe logging uses `WARNING` as a default value for logging to the terminal. Try to add another handler, using `logging.StreamHandler` as a class.

Comment: @Alex.P Thanks for your input. I added a handler that outputted to console, unfortunately it gave the same output. See my edit for what I added to the JSON file. Note that I am intending to write the logging to a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, I figured out what was wrong. Turns out it was the JSON.
From [this example](https://gist.github.com/glenfant/4358668) which I was basing my work off of, it has an extra `logging` property in the JSON, which encapsulates all the loggers, handlers etc.

Removing that property and having the hierarchy more like a YAML file (which I also tested, and got working correctly), it works as expected. I could even remove the extra call to `basicConfig` in my `logger.py`.

Final JSON;

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": "false",
    "formatters": {
        "basic": {
            "class": "logging.Formatter",
            "datefmt": "%I:%M:%S",
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s"
        }
    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "basic",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "basic",
            "filename": "test.log",
            "mode": "w",
            "encoding": "utf-8"
        }
    },

    "loggers": { },

    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console", "file"],
        "level": "DEBUG"
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could have a "root" field in the dictconfig.

Comment: I learned from you that utf-8 must be specified in case the code runs on other machines with different charset.